# From list to tree representation

Tags: python, list, recursion, tree, generator

Hello I have a list (in Python 3) like this :

```
lista=[ ['a','b','c','d'],['b','f','g'],['c','h','i'],['d'],['h'],['i'],['f'],['g']]
```

and I'm trying to translate it in a nested list like this

```
['a',['b',['f'],['g']],['c',['h'],['i']],['d']]]
```

so it's like this tree :

```
              a
            / | \
          b   c  d
         /\   /\
       f  g   h i
```

I thought to use a generator like this

```
listb = [ lista[0][0]] + [x for x in lista[1:] ]
```

but I don't know how to iterate recursively through the whole list.
Thank you!

Comment: `listb=[lista[0][0]]+[x for x in lista[1:]]` is not a generator, it's just a list comprehension

Comment: are you sure you need this nested list? a dict seems a much better type than a nested list for this kind of task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
lista=[ ['a','b','c','d'],['b','f','g'],['c','h','i'],['d'],['h'],['i'],['f'],['g']]

def tree(root, d):
    return [root] + [tree(k, d) for k in d[root]]

d = {i[0]: i[1:] for i in lista}

root = 'a'
print(tree(root, d))
```

which prints this out:

```
['a', ['b', ['f'], ['g']], ['c', ['h'], ['i']], ['d']]
```

Although I believe the dictionary (d) itself might serve you better.

Comment: Thank you , so it's a better idea use the dictionary {'d': [], 'i': [], 'b': ['f', 'g'], 'a': ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'c': ['h', 'i'], 'h': [], 'f': [], 'g': []} for a tree structure ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Of course it all depends on your use case, but  a dictionary you can give you the children to any node you with a convenient syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
def nodeinline(head, nodes):
    return [head] + [nodeinline(child, nodes) for child in nodes.get(head, [])]

def nodebyref_to_nodeinline(lst):
    head  = lst[0][0]
    nodes = {node[0]: node[1:] for node in lst}
    return nodeinline(head, nodes)

nodebyref_to_nodeinline([['a','b','c','d'],['b','f','g'],['c','h','i'],['d'],['h'],['i'],['f'],['g']])
```

gives

```
['a', ['b', ['f'], ['g']], ['c', ['h'], ['i']], ['d']]
```